# Loadrunner: Store many of xml file contents in an array and one by one call array

Tags: c, loadrunner

I have five hundred xml files, I want to store file contents into a array or list. use Loadrunner call array and send xml files to application server, But I am not familiar with c. 
example：

Result01.xml,Result02.xml,Result03.xml,Result4.xml,Result05.xml,....Result500.xml,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CPU, Disk, Memory, Network.  This is your finite resource pool. Attempting, for every single virtual user, to pull all XML files into memory is going to drive the memory requirements for each virtual user through the roof and you will very likely wind up in a swap of death model on your load generator.

Consider storing all of the names of your files and their location on a very fast SSD local to the load generator in a parameter file.  Select from that file randomly for the filename.  Read it from disk and then submit it as appropriate.  This will limit your in memory need to the size of your largest XML file, which you can free() as soon as you are done using the file.  This does introduce a disk dependency, but note it is a read only dependency and the recommendation to used SSD for the storage is because of the absurdly high read IOPS on that media to reduce the window of conflict to an absolute minimum.

This is also a good time to brush up on your C programming.  There are lots of great books out there. You need to be proficient with the language of your tool, no matter what the tool is, if you are going to be effective with the tool.